# change a key of a single element array

Tags: php

I have an array tree from a database,  I want to change the key of a child element in this case the second array 'eric'=>array into integer '0'=>array as follow :

```
0 => Array
    ('text' => 'paris',
     'nodes' => Array
            ('eric' => Array
                    (  'text' => 'eric',
                       'nodes' => Array
                           (0 => Array
                               (
                                'text' => 'so.png',              
                               ),
                           ),
                    ),
            ),
   ),
```

there is my code :

```
while($d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if(!isset($data[$d['country']])) {
       $data[$d['country']] = array(
         'text' => $d['country'],
         'nodes' => array()  
       ); 
    }
    if(!isset($data[$d['country']]['nodes'][$d['name']])) {
        $data[$d['country']]['nodes'][$d['name']] = array(
          'text' => $d['name'],
          'nodes' => array()
        );    
     }
    array_push($data[$d['country']]['nodes'][$d['name']]['nodes'], $d['n_doc']);
}
```

Comment: What is stopping you?

Comment: And? Do you get any errors? Does it work? Does it not?

Comment: [$ d ['name']] Is there anything that changes the key to this element and the make it 0

Comment: i do not have an error but I want to change the key of this array element [$ d ['name']]  to 0 -1 -2

Comment: `$data[$d['country']]['nodes'][$d['name']]  = array(...` is the place to look at

Comment: After all `$data[$d['country']]['nodes']` = array_values($data[$d['country']]['nodes']);`

Comment: splash58- where exactly in my code

Comment: no idea for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change all of the child keys to numeric values, you can simply just use array_values()

> [Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/p1t1C)

```
for($i = 0; $i <= count($data) -1; $i++) { # This loops through each country
    $data[$i]['nodes'] = array_map(function($node) { # This preserves the parent text value
        return array_values($node); # [0] => Paris, [1] => array(...)
    }, $data[$i]['nodes']);
}
```

> Output
>
> ```
> [ ... => [ text => Paris, nodes => [ 0 => Paris, 1 => [ ... ] ] ... ] ... ]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

can you change your code for this input:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => paris
            [nodes] => Array
                (
                    [jacque] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => jacque
                            [nodes] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 32.png
                                )
                        )

                    [anis] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => anis
                            [nodes] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 5384a97ee9d6b (2).pd
                                )
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => london
            [nodes] => Array
                (
                    [dodo] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => dodo
                            [nodes] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 148782.svg
                                    [1] => 333.png
                                )

                        )

                    [sd] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => sd
                            [nodes] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1014-favicon.ico
                                )

                        )

                   )
        )
)
```